# How do you make a program that counts characters in a text widget in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, logic

I am trying to make a program that counts the number of characters in the text widget. However, I am running into an error, how do I get past this error?

Here is my code so far:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600)

# Declare Find Chars Function
def declareFindChars():
    chars = text.get("1.0", END)
    printChars = len(chars)
    print(printChars)

# Initialize Find Char Function
def initFindChars():
    declareFindChars()
    text.after(1, initFindChars) # THIS SHOWS THE CHARACTERS EVERY ONE MILISECOND

text = Text(root, width=50, height=50).pack()

initFindChars()
root.mainloop()
```

So I want to print how many characters there are in the text widget every 1 milliseconds. How do I get passed the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")

text = Text(root, width=50, height=50)

# Declare Find Chars Function
def declareFindChars():
    chars = text.get("1.0", END)
    printChars = len(chars)
    print(printChars)

# Initialize Find Char Function
def initFindChars():
    declareFindChars()
    text.after(1, initFindChars) # THIS SHOWS THE CHARACTERS EVERY ONE MILISECOND

text.pack()

initFindChars()
root.mainloop()
```

This should work. I tested in PyCharm.
It was returning NoneType because the Text() object was not initialized before the function, so therefore it was None/Null.

Comment: I also noticed that it adds one extra character on even though there's
not one there. To fix that replace printChars = len(chars) with
printChars = len(chars) - 1

Comment: Thanks, it works, is there a reason for packing the textbox after the functions though?

Comment: No, you can pack the textbox wherever and it'll work as long as it is
below creating the text variable of course

Comment: To be a better answer, you should explain what you have changed.